# How do I programmatically make bodies sleep and wake?

Tags: javascript, sleep, matter.js

In the [sleeping example](http://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#sleeping) ([source](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/master/examples/sleeping.js)), the bodies go to sleep after a few seconds of inactivity. This is accomplished with:

```
Engine.create({
    enableSleeping: true
});
```

It's possible to detect when bodies are sleeping or waking up (with the `sleepStart` and `sleepEnd` events), but how can I *cause* a body to start or end sleeping?

Comment: using Matter.Sleeping.set http://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Sleeping.html#method_set

Comment: @Asthmatic That looks like an answer! The answer box is below. ☺

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Matter.Sleeping.set`](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Sleeping.html#method_set):

```
Matter.Sleeping.set(body, false); // sleep
Matter.Sleeping.set(body, true);  // wake
```

(Credit [WilliamNHarvey](/users/6301806/williamnharvey).)